# Out of string space error in vba

Tags: vba, out-of-memory, powerpoint

I am getting this error sometimes while creating a huge file in vba (when it worked I check the created file and it has 1.626.756 characters). I have to store all the characters of the file in a string and then open a file and insert it to the file and close it.

Apparently it was something that happen when your computer gets out of memory to store the string.

I check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264524%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

It says this "Your system may have run out of memory, which prevented a string from being allocated.
Remove any unnecessary applications from memory to create more space." But this is not really a solution.

Is there any other way to avoid this error?

Comment: I would post an example of the code that produces this error.  If in fact the problem is due to lack of string space, it may occur unpredictably on your system and other systems.  In that case you may want to concoct another way of storing the information.  W/o knowing exactly what you're doing, it's impossible to make any suggestions though.

Comment: Probably you can review your code and optimize the declaration of variables. It should solve your problem. Still, it would be much helpful if you can post your code.